# Can I start over on another server?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I will get the SWTOR CE shortly and I was wondering with that many servers available, I will sort of need to find out which one is best for me, given that friends from guilds in other games may settle on a server different than what I may pick when I get the game.

Is it possible to create a character on another server, given that you loose your progress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get back to the server selection screen by clicking the back button on bottom left on the character selection screen.

Take a look at [TorStatus.net](http://www.torstatus.net/). It lists all of the current SWTOR servers and provides graph listings of server population over time. You can see which servers are the busiest and at what times.

Right now it's best to avoid the high population servers, unless you like queuing up to enter.